# React-router push callback?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, flux

I need to trigger a synchronous action after react-router push, which appears to be async

Is it possible to do something like:

```
dispatch(push('/', callbackFunction))
```

I don't see anything in the react-router docs about a callback to `push`, which seems quite odd...

Answer (score 1):

As it seems, `push` is not asynchronous since it is just an action creator (factory pattern).

So you could trigger you actions like this:

```
dispatch(push('/'));
dispatch(otherAction());
```

[Relevant lines](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/d64ed0150b41df02b083f090b6682261c819a91e/packages/react-router-redux/modules/actions.js#L21)