# React Router Callback on Transition

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-router-redux

I have a project using React Router and Redux. When pushing a new location to history with dispatch, I would love it if I could include a callback like this:

`dispatch(push(page, callback));`

I found another question on SO that is asking the [same thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41762677/react-router-push-callback), but I was unsatisfied with the answer provided (to use `onEnter()` in the Routes).

Is there a way to do this, or a reasonable alternative?

Comment: Can you describe the use case in which you would like to do this? It may help to describe what you are trying to do so that we can think up viable alternatives. If you are looking to execute a function after the page transition, is placing the function in the componentWIllMount or componentDidMount of the transitioned-to route not viable in your use case?

Comment: The use case is I would like to focus an input after the page has been transitioned `document.querySelector("input#handle").focus();`

You're right, this is definitely an option and would work. I don't like it though, because the solution is _imperative_, and breaks the _reactive_ paradigm that Redux is all about.

Comment: Redux is not to handle such impure things. `componentDidMount` is the most viable option. Redux is to help the flow of data around application intact and not for such things.

You might like to go through this - https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/1385

Comment: Ok good to know, thanks! I will try this out